# AddHandler Object

Tags: vb.net, object, events, observablecollection

I need add the collectionchanged's event to collection object:

```
Dim Coleccion As Object = New ObservableCollection(Of Entidad)

AddHandler Coleccion.CollectionChanged, AddressOf Coleccion_Cambiada
```

But it throws: CollectionChanged is not event for object

So, i tried:

```
Dim Evento As EventInfo = Coleccion.GetType().GetEvent("CollectionChanged")

Evento.AddEventHandler(Coleccion, New EventHandler(AddressOf Coleccion_Cambiada))
```

But it throws: Can't convert System.EventHandler to System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler

So, how can i add a event for a generic observablecollection that i dont know?

Thanks.

Comment: `Dim Coleccion As Object` declares the collection as `Object` which hides the interface and methods for `ObservableCollection`.  Pretty much just what the message says

Comment: ok, but i need add the event to a dynamic collection, where i don't know what it is,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting when you try to add the event handler using reflection is because the CollectionChanged event doesn't use the default eventhandler.  You can fix the error by using the specific eventhandler that is used by the CollectionChanged event.

```
Evento.AddEventHandler(Coleccion, New System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(AddressOf Coleccion_Cambiada))
```

Comment: Hell, thanks.. i thought AddEventHandler were wrong to collections, and not the New EventHandler